# collection to string in laravel 5.2 query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make query in laravel 5.2 to fetch agencies table which has a foreign key with organizations table using agencies.organization_id=organizations.id. Now Users table has also foreign key with organizations table using users.organization_id=organizations.id. Now how to fetch agency table that which agencies are linked with users_id.

```
public function postagency(Request $request) {
        $user_id = $request->user_id;
        $org_id = User::where('id', $user_id)->pluck('organization_id')->first();
        $postagencies = agency::where('organization_id', $org_id);
        echo $postagencies;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I understand is that an user can only be under one organisation and an organisation has many agencies. If not please say so and I will alter my answer.

First of all set your relationships inside your models. An example would be:

```
// User.php

public function organization()
{

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Organization'); // App\Organization can be changed depending on the used namespace

}
```

More info can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships). If you need some more examples just ask.

After you have created these relationships you can retrieve your agency like this:

```
$user= User::find($request->user_id);

if (!$user) ... // Check if user exists

$agencies = $user->organisation->agencies;
```

If I need to explain things in more detail just ask. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks it's working.. add a hasmany() relatioship in organization.php... :)